# Missing initial state in WebAuthenticator login attempt

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, maui

working on a .NET MAUI app and am trying to implement Firebase Authentication with the help of WebAuthenticator in MAUI. I get to the login form in a browser, but after logging in get the error

> Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared.

This is the code that calls the authenticator

```
 await client.SignInWithRedirectAsync(FirebaseProviderType.Google, async uri =>
            {
                var options = new WebAuthenticatorOptions
                {
                    Url = new Uri(uri),
                    CallbackUrl = new Uri("com.companyname.myappname://callback/"),
                    PrefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession= true
                };


                var res = await WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(options);
            });
```

I think the problem could be the callback URL, but I'm not sure how to write it differently since I'm not using a backend API. Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

P.S. This happens with bost Firebase Google auth and Facebook login

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear the chrome browser data and reload the page to see if it works. This is a known problem of firebase. You can continue to follow up this github iissue: [Unableto process request due to missing initial state.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4256)